AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be found. when GenerateAssemblyInfo is false but duplicate error when turn on
i am quite new in asp.net and want to structure my project accordingly
MyMainProject-Folder
    - WebApi1 (webapi)
        - WebApi1.csproj
        - Controllers
            - Controllers.csproj
        - Contracts
            - Contracts.csproj
    - WebApi2 (webapi)
    - CommonStuff (classlib)
    - Directory.Build.props
    - Directory.Build.targets
    - Directory.Packages.props 

my csproj file contains

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>Project.WebAPi1.Controllers</RootNamespace>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>false</GenerateTargetFrameworkAttribute>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Reference the Contracts project -->
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contracts\Contracts.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <ProjectReference Include="../../CommonStuff/Core/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


this is the error i am getting while building the project
CSC : error CS2001: Source file '/home/ujwal/Documents/personal/*Project/webapi1/Controllers/obj/Debug/net8.0/Controllers.AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be found. [/home/ujwal/Documents/personal/*Project/Webapi1/Webapi1.csproj]
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>

or dont include this line it gives duplicate assembly Error
but if i do
any type of discussion is helpful. I can provide other information as needed

Have you got a .csproj in one folder, and another .csproj in a subfolder of off that one? If so you will need to exclude the subfolder from the project in its parent folder.

Don't have one project as sub folder of another project and your life will improve.

yes webapi one got csproj and controller which is inside csproj also have csproj
i have seen some project with these patterns and wanted to recreate/try it
if you have a better solution I am all yours
